# A Basic Class Problem about String and the object returned

Tags: java, class

This is a question about Java Class from my school previous quiz. I cannot handle it and can anyone help or offer some tips please? Thanks a lot.

[image]

For my answer in class A:

```
public String A (String name){
     return name;
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I guess this should be the constructor of class `A`. Am I right? Constructors don't have return values!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 'A's are an object, you need a constructor. So you would likely have something like:

```
public A(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
```

After this, you need to overwrite toString(), since 'A's are objects and printing them normally will not work. Thus, you would then need:

```
public String toString(){
    return this.name;
}
```

Thus, when you call S.o.PL(), it will run this version instead of Object.toString()

Answer (score 0):

Consider method with name A, where you are creating an object of A and can pass the parameter as a string, then the method A can return a string which belongs to the variable

called name = myvalue;

**It Means**

```
public A(String name){
this.name = name;}
String name = myvalue;
```